# Android database insert went wrong

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i create a database and a table. This went well.

```
 // Create Database
        matDb = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(path + "/test.db", null);
      matDb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ammTbl + "(werk text, matnum text, mattxt text, unit text, loc text, chargenpflicht text)");
```

On the device I can find the database and the table.
I inserted data. The object mh has the values!:

```
matDb.beginTransaction();

 ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
                row.put("werk", plant);
                row.put("matnum", mh.getMatnum());
                row.put("unit", mh.getUnit());
                row.put("mattxt", mh.getMattxt());

 matDb.insertOrThrow(ammTbl, null, row);
 matDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
 matDb.endTransaction();
 matDb.close();
```

An exception didn't raise. No data is inserted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the evidence for "No data is inserted"?

Comment: There is nothing in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You @LittleProgrammer need to do

matdb=getWritableDatabase();

before inserting the values into the table